# Twilio Chat push notifications

Tags: push-notification, chat, twilio

We are using the twilio-chat@1.0.4 JS SDK in our react-native app.
We're using react-native-push-notification@3.0.0 to handle the notifications.
The pushes are enabled and can see them coming through from twilio.
But I can't figure out how to turn on alerts.
I can (and currently do) issue a local notification when the app is in the background but we'd like to see the alert even if the app is closed.

How can we configure the push notifications to include an alert.

Comment: How are pushes enabled and how are you registering for them with the Twilio Chat JavaScript?

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/push-notification-configuration) to enable pushes. And we're using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to register.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar needs but the only difference in my case am using twilio native chat wrapper instead of the JS sdk.

To enable have push notifications working I ended up forking https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification and customizing it to support twilio push notifications which have custom payload than what you might be used to.

Check https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/compare/master...Kabangi:master for the changes I made you might get some ideas from it.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Chat JS 1.1.1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/changelogs/javascript#programmable-chat-111-august-16-2017) was recently released and actually contains methods for dealing with push notifications.

Also, did you follow the instructions for [React Native's PushNotificationIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content) that explain how to setup your iOS application for receiving push notifications?

Comment: I'm setting up Android/FCM messages. I've set everything up, and receive the messages. The problem is that they arrive as data messages not notification messages (as defined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: For android please follow the steps in the demo app to send this as notification internally: see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/chat-demo-android/src/main/java/com/twilio/chat/demo/FCMListenerService.java#L29

Comment: I did that and the push work, sort of. The problem is that the app needs to be running to send the notification to the status bar on android).

Comment: Can I ask how you are closing the application to test this?